# Open user specified Excel workbook and copy data range to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro in Excel where the user chooses a file to open and the macro will copy a range from that workbook and paste it to a user specified cell in the original workbook. My attempt at the code is shown below. I have "wbThis" as the original workbook to be pasted to and "wbTarget" as the workbook that is being opened and copied from. When I run the code, I can choose what file I want to open but it gives an error saying "Object required" and doesn't proceed further into copying and pasting.

Is there a way to use Workbook.Open instead of Application.GetOpenFilename but still have the user be able to choose what file to open?

Thank you for your help.

```
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbTarget = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbook (*.xls),*.xls", Title:="Open data")

wbThis.Activate
Set rDest = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the Cell to paste to", Title:="Paste to", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
wbTarget.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbTarget.Range("A1").Select
wbTarget.Range("B6:B121").Copy
wbThis.Activate
rDest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbTarget.Close False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetOpenFileName does not really opens a file, just gets it's name.
Try doing `Application.Workbooks.Open(TheResultOfGetOpenFileName)`

```
dim FileName as string
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbook (*.xls),*.xls", Title:="Open data")

Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I had to change one other thing in the code for it to work correctly, which I have shown below.

`Range("A1").Select
Range("B6:B121").Copy`